# Boost library acceptance in industry

Tags: c++, boost

I have seen lots of people suggesting the Boost library on Stack Overflow, so I am also thinking of learning it. But today I came across this link: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Boost
I wanted to know about its acceptance in industry at a broader level. My current company also doesn't allow me to use this so I am confused whether to look into this or not.

Comment: Google's C++ style guide is notoriously bad. Ignore it, and you'll live a much happier life. :)

Comment: Google's guide is for keeping an **old** C++ code base alive as long as possible. Not recommended for new code!

Comment: Google's guide is absolutely *terrible* for writing C++, ignore it.

Comment: I went to look at that guide with 'no-script' activated.  It turns into a continuous block of text with no formatting.  I thought it was a joke, writing a code-styleguide in the style that no code should ever be written in.

Comment: Pedantic, but important: Boost is **not** a library, it is a collection of libraries. Many companies allow some Boost libs and not others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parts of Boost library is currently being accepted into the Standard library for C++0x and it is regarded as one of the top libs with a high industry acceptance. I'm actually unaware of any other library getting accepted into the C++ Standard Library on such a large scale.

"Ten Boost libraries are already included in the C++ Standards Committee's Library Technical Report (TR1) and will be in the new C++0x Standard now being finalized. C++0x will also include several more Boost libraries in addition to those from TR1. More Boost libraries are proposed for TR2."

Comment: Software industry and never met deadlines:)

Comment: Anyway, it can't be c++0x, maybe c++1x

Comment: @Ubiquité: surely you meant C++0xB ?

Answer (score 6):

You should definately look into this.  Don't go by Google or any other large institution.  They generally have to work to a subset of any complex language like C++.  Hence, they'll have restrictions on which parts they can use so that it's easier to hire and train engineers to use the code base.

Additionally, Boost leverages many aspects of the higher forms of functionality within C++, case in point template meta-programming.  Boost provides for a safer, though bulkier, form of functions as first class objects.  They add in a more powerful "bind" which works so well with the standard  library that I'd be lost without it.  Finally, they have in place tuples and hash tables, both fundamental datatypes in modern development libraries.

In short, I really can't name one reason why you wouldn't want to look at Boost, even just to learn something.  It's peer reviewed and largely platform independent.  The source code is a treasure trove of information and more advanced programming techniques.

Answer (score 3):

I think the *who is using boost* [web page](http://www.boost.org/users/uses_shrink.html) speaks for itself. Notably: Adobe, McAfee, and Real Networks probably qualify as industry.

> My current company also does not allow me
>   to use [boost]. So I am confused whether
>   to look into it or not.

You might want to dig a little further and find out why. As others have said, Boost is a fantastically useful set of open source and peer reviewed libraries of extremely high quality. Look at their [development LOC chart](http://www.boost.org/development/index.html) for an idea how long and how much $$ it would cost your company to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `Notably: Adobe, McAfee, and Real Networks` wow... I can't believe boost advertises these three... next they're going to say iTunes on windows uses boost

Comment: u got a problem dawg?